# Collada (.DAE) file not rendering all faces of 3D model

Tags: three.js, aframe, sketchup, 3d-modelling

We have some models that were created in the 3D modeling program, SketchUp Pro and we exported that model as a Collada file (.DAE). However, after exporting the model, we’ve noticed that some of the faces of the model are missing and thus their textures are not being applied.

Is this a rendering issue with Three.js? We're importing our models into A-FRAME, the web framework that Three.js is built on top of.

If anyone has run across this issue before, is there a way to correct it?

When I view the exported DAE file in Preview on the Mac, the model's faces are completely intact with no issues.

Comment: Try `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;`

Comment: @WestLangley I get an error that `material` is not defined when I add that line of code to my Javascript.

Comment: You will need to show your code, then.

Comment: Besides, sharing the `dae` file would be also helpful to solve this issue.

Comment: Here's the link to download the DAE file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6dqend1sj1purc/WestLibraryWing.dae?dl=0.

When this DAE file is included in A-FRAME, that's where you'll see the missing faces.  If you need me to create a test page, please let me know.